# how the 'tmpdata' and 'Get_Parameter_List' works in OracleForm?

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters, procedure, oracleforms

I am new in OracleForms and Plsql, i found this code in a proyect:

```
PROCEDURE grabar IS
...
    Pl_id paramlist;
...
BEGIN
    pl_id := Get_Parameter_List ('tmpdata'); 
    IF NOT Id_Null(pl_id) THEN 
        Destroy_Parameter_List( pl_id ); 
    END IF; 
    pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
```

i want to konw that if 'tmpdata' does not exist i will get an error? 
whit the line:
    pl_id := Get_Parameter_List ('tmpdata'); 
am i inserting the data of 'tmpdata' in 'PL_id'
it is the 'tmpdata' a default variable of Oracleforms or something?

[it is not OracleForms but it is a tool based in it so is so similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dDqH.png)

I proved to change to:
    `pl_id := Get_Parameter_List ('tmpdata_HELLO');` 
enter code hereand the program passed to of this 
the console show me this:

> may 25, 2018 4:46:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
>   INFORMACIÓN: Character decoding failed. Parameter [value] with value [%null] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
>
> Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with Oracle Forms. The Oracle Forms, at least versions before 12, has very good help. Just check built in Help. As far as I remember the tmpdata is the name of rhe parameter list. Then you create and add parameters to this list - Create_Parameter_List.... Add_Parameter.... Then you pass this parameter list to other form with call_form usually or report. Thing to remember. When you coming back from called form to the calling form your When-New-Form-Instance trigger will not fire. Use when-form-navigate if i remember correctly. Check built in help, it is great.

Comment: WHy not see what happens if you try an incorrect name, e.g.  pl_id := Get_Parameter_List ('tmpdata_HELLO');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, "tmpdata" is the name of a parameter list that may or may not exist.  The "ID_NULL" is checking for the existence of the parameter list by checking of the ID returned has a value or not.  If it has a value (ie, ID_NULL returns FALSE), then the parameter list is destroyed so that the "Create_Parameter_List" command will not get an error.

"Get_Parameter_List" will not throw an error if there is no parameter list by the given name ("tmpdata", in this case); it just returns null.

Comment: thanks for commet ths was that i needed. so 'tmpdata'  is a convention used in this type of projects?

Comment: No, "tmpdata" has no particular meaning or convention; it's just whatever the developer wanted to name the parameter list.  He could have called it "My_Param_List", or "Fred_Flintstone".  The name doesn't matter, as long as it has the same value everywhere it's referenced.  Our application has names like "TCLIST" and "HLP_PARAM_LIST".